# Injectivity of $-2p(x)+xp′(x)$ over cubic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Consider the transformation $T:P_3(\mathbb R)\to P_3(\mathbb R)$, $T(p(x))=-2p(x)+xp'(x)$. Is this linear transformation mentioned injective?

I would appreciate your help for this question above.

I understand to find whether it is injective or not, I have to find $T(v) = 0$ for which $v\ne0$ exists.

I have expanded the RHS and to me, it seems to be non-injective.

However, I need more confirmation for this as to me it's quite tough.

Comment: Does $P_3$ refer to quadratic polynomials or cubic ones?

Comment: Hello Parcly!, I suspect it refers to cubic polynomials :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $T$ is not injective, we have to prove that $\operatorname{Ker}T\neq \{0\}$, i.e. find a non-zero polynomial $p\in \mathbf{R}[X]_{\leqslant 3}$ for which $T(p)\neq 0$.

Note that $T(X^2)=-2\cdot X^2+X\cdot 2X=0$, hence $T$ is not injective.

Comment: Great! Thanks rae306 for your help! It makes sense when I use an example of 10X^2 :)

Comment: Great! $T$ is linear, so if $X^2$ is sent to zero, then so is $10X^2$, $2020X^2$ or whatever ;) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Treating polynomials as vectors with the first coefficient representing the constant term, we have
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
-2+0&0&0&0\\
0&-2+1&0&0\\
0&0&-2+2&0\\
0&0&0&-2+3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
The determinant is zero, so $T$ is not injective. A non-trivial vector in the nullspace of $T$ is $(0,0,1,0)^T$, which corresponds to $p(x)=x^2$; we may verify that applying $T$ to this polynomial returns $0$.